# Does an equipped creature become an artifact creature?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Does a creature become an artifact creature when an artifact is equipped onto it or just a creature with an artifact on it?

Answer (score 4):

No, an artifact creature is specifically a creature that has "artifact" written in its type line. See [Platinum Emperion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Platinum%20Emperion) for an example; it specifically says "artifact creature". A creature could also become an artifact creature through an effect that says it changes the type, such as [Mycosynth Lattice](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mycosynth%20Lattice). But attaching an equipment to a creature will not affect the creature's types unless that equipment specifically says something like "equipped creature is an artifact in addition to its other types" such as [Silverskin Armor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Silverskin%20Armor).

Comment: e.g. Silverskin Armor